# Google Apps Script - return output from apps script function back to the html file javascript function

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

Ok, so I am trying to make a function in google sheets that when the user selects a cell and then runs the function (currently trying to make), a sidebar getting all the synonyms of the word should appear. I am using https://words.bighugelabs.com/ to get the synonyms. So first I make the menu:

```
`function onOpen(e) {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu("Sidebar")
  .addItem("Get Synonym", 'showSidebar')
  .addToUi();
}`
```

Then this is the showSidebar function:

```
function showSidebar() {
      var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile("Test")
      .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME)
      .setWidth(150)
      .setTitle("My Sidebar");
      SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showSidebar(html);
    }
```

This is the html file:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<base target="_top">
<script>

function doSomething() {
var synonyms = google.script.run.getSynonym();
document.getElementById("synonyms").innerHTML = synonyms;
}

</script>
</head>
<body>
<div>
<span style="color:orange;">This is a test sidebar!</span>
<button onclick="doSomething()">Click Me!</button>
<div id="synonyms"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

And this is the getSynonym function:

```
function getSynonym() {
  var word = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange().getValue();
  var synonyms = [];
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch("http://words.bighugelabs.com/api/2/{my_api_key}/" + word + "/json");
  response = JSON.parse(response);
  var synonyms = response.adjective.syn;
  return synonyms;
}
```

But the variable synonyms which as an array of synonyms doesn't get returned to the doSomething function in the Html file.

What I want is that the sidebar should get a list of all the synonyms. 
So basically I can't get the data from one function to another...and I want to know if this is the right way.

Comment: Why are you not calling that api in sidebar html itself ?

Comment: I tried that. I don't think I know how to do that properly. Need help with it. But besides that, I want to know if the thing I want is actually possible (transferring data from the apps script function to the javascript function in the html file

Comment: 1. You can make simple ajax request, 2. yes, you can. But since you want to pass array, you need to investigate a bit. Single data can be passed easily.

Comment: Thanks, I don't know much about ajax. Can you provide links/resources where I can learn how to ajax requests and secondly, how can single data be passed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When calling server side functions using `google.script.run` you need to define a success handler, which will asynchronously receive your response.

See the examples on: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication

```
  function onSuccess(synonyms ) {
    console.log(synonyms);
  }

  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onSuccess).doSomething();
```